# InputStreams and OutputStreams

Tags: java, inputstream, outputstream

I wrote this short program which has a tiny GUI. Its supposed to allow you to type text and then you can save it to a txt file or read from a previously saved file or delete an existing file.
It works, but with some strange bugs. Sometimes after a file is created, if I try to delete it, it will not delete the file.

Also, Im totally not sure if I wrote the code in a good way. 
I was wondering if you can have a look at what I wrote and find weaknesses or areas that I should write differently. And also maybe you can see why there is a problem with deleting the file after it was created. I'm really at a loss and I don't know who to ask.
Here is the code I have:

```
public class InputOutout extends JFrame{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7073762217756427192L;

    JLabel label;
    JTextField tf;
    JButton buttonAdd;
    JButton buttonDisplay;
    JButton buttonErase;

    public InputOutout() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        label = new JLabel("Enter text");
        add(label);

        tf = new JTextField(10);
        add(tf);

        buttonAdd = new JButton("Press to save to file");
        add(buttonAdd);

        buttonDisplay = new JButton("Press to display file content");
        add(buttonDisplay);

        buttonErase = new JButton("Press to erase file");
        add(buttonErase);

        eventAdd add = new eventAdd();
        eventDisplay remove = new eventDisplay();
        eventErase erase = new eventErase();

        buttonAdd.addActionListener(add);
        buttonDisplay.addActionListener(remove);
        buttonErase.addActionListener(erase);       
    }

    private class eventAdd implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                String word = tf.getText()+ " ";
                FileWriter stream = new FileWriter("text.txt",true);
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(stream);
                out.append(word);
                out.close();
                tf.setText("");
            } catch (Exception ex){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex.getMessage());
            }

        }
    }

    private class eventDisplay implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                FileReader stream = new FileReader("text.txt");
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(stream);
                String text = in.readLine();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, text);
                stream.close();
            } catch (Exception ex){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex.getMessage());
            }

        }
    }

    private class eventErase implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                File file = new File("text.txt");
                boolean success = file.delete();

                if (!success) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File was not deleted");
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File was deleted");
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        InputOutout gui = new InputOutout();

        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.setSize(350,100);
        gui.setTitle("SuperWORD 2013");
        gui.setVisible(true);       
    }
}
```

Comment: If possible, you should try to remove some of your less relevant code listed.  At the very least you can remove your import statements.

Comment: so you get your JOptionPane saying it wasn't deleted? Please tell us what happens if it 'refuses to delete'

Comment: I can collapse the import code if that is what you mean? Or do you mean deleting it entirely. But then the code wont run...

Comment: Nothing happens. The file stays intact and I get my JOptionPane to say the file was not deleted. What do you mean tell you what happens?

Comment: Additionally, whenever you catch, you `catch (Exception ex)`. This could lead to exceptions being caught and discarded that you might have wanted to know about.

Comment: You mean not use Exception but the specific exception that might occur? For example IOException instead of just Exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic surrounding the `file.delete()` is not quite correct, as `true` will only be returned if it is deleted. This means that `file.delete()` will return `false` if it does not exist. Check if the file exists before attempting to delete it:

```
File file = new File("text.txt");
if (file.exists())
{
    if (!file.delete())
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File was not deleted");
    }
    else
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File was deleted");
    }
}
else
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File does not exist");
}
```

Recommend using a `try {} catch() finally {}` construct to ensure `BufferedReader.close()`, or `BufferedWriter.close()` is called:

```
try
{
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("text.txt",true));
    try
    {
        String word = tf.getText()+ " ";
        out.append(word);
        tf.setText("");
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            out.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            // Report close failure.
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Report open or write failure.
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Ohh. Could that be the reason why the delete function sometimes fails?

Comment: Alright thank you! I'll try that. Other than that, do you see any code that I should have wrote differently?

Comment: Ohh I see. Alright I'll add that right away. And I see that you used the BufferedWriter out to call the .close() function. Am Im supposed to close the BufferedWriter or reader instead of the stream itself?

Comment: Call it on the `BufferedWriter()/BufferReader()`.